# Re-position image and then shrink it while screen gets smaller, no media queries

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

So, basically I have a table row with 2 cells, with the first cell (on the left) containing text, and the right one containing an image. While the screen gets smaller and smaller, I want the image to eventually move under the text. After some research I finally found and understood how the display and flex property works and have solved that issue.

In the table row properties I have inserted

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

and for each cell you put `flex: 1 1 10ch;` for example. I have found this [here](https://polypane.app/blog/4-css-layouts-without-using-media-queries/), which certainly explains more and better.

So, now what I want is when the image is repositioned under the text, to shrink when the screen gets smaller than the image itself. The image's size is fixed because with percentage is just gets smaller and does not reposition. I have also tried `max-width` but it doesn't change anything I think.

```html
<div>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 3% 0 0; flex: 3 1 50ch;">
          <p>Some random text. Normally, the text is much more.</p>
        </td>
        <td align="justify" style="padding: 0.5%; flex: 1 1 10ch;"><img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" width="500"  /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I also lose the vertical alignment for the text. Is there any way to align it to the middle again?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with your code to show us what you have. Also, why no media queries? That is the standard way to detect breakpoints.

Comment: Use codepen or another service. Easy for you to show us what is wrong, and easy for us to give you advice.

Comment: @GerryMM88 Actually the preferred way to add code here is using the `[<>]` button on the editor toolbar to create a runnable Stack Snippet directly in the question. External links are discouraged on Stack Overflow as they can break or change, which makes the question invalid and no longer useful to other users. It is ok to include them as long as the relevant code/information is also included here in the question itself.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I cannot use media queries, as this is something for my university and there are limitations to the possibilites for the website designing.

Comment: FYI, when you are asking homework questions, you should indicate this in the question :) See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @FluffyKitten It’s not actually for homework. I work part-time for my university and I manage some of the webpages for a few departments. I just wanted to understand how to do this and also learn myself how to this is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the `object-fit` property on the image,
this will resize the image to fit the container:

```
img{
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It kind of works, I think. But it makes the image smaller before repositioning it. Also, with the percentage is not at the size that I would like. Thanks for your answer though, I might eventually use it too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ch` as units here. It can be misleading, and doesn't work reliably with variable width fonts. With images, it can be even worse. Stick to `em`, `rem`, or even `px`. I used the latter.

Flex is more flexible than the example had shown you. See the comments in the code.

```css
.tbl {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.first {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 3% 0 0;
  flex: 3 1 auto; /*don't care about the basis of this element as it always grows and shrinks as required*/
}

.second {
  padding: 0.5%;
  flex: 0 1 500px; /* never grow, only shrink when required, 500px basis (from your example) */
}

.second img {
  width: 100%; /*The image should always be as wide as its parent allows to be.*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tbl">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="first">
          <p>Some random text. Normally, the text is much more.</p>
        </td>
        <td align="justify" class="second"><img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For .first, 'auto' does not work, it throws the image under the text no matter the size of the screen. It somehow works now, maybe with the object-fit property that I added from the other comment.